# Pivot in Pandas incorrectly converts index column to row labels ... losing the index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, row

The dataframe smaller_df looks like this:

```
> smaller_df.head()
   MSA Code  Line   RPP
0     10180   1.0  91.2
1     10180   2.0  97.4
2     10180   3.0  78.7
3     10180   4.0  93.5
4     10420   1.0  90.4
...
```

wage_keys.head() gives:

```
   MSA Code  Average Wage
0     11260  94490.000000
1     21820  72080.000000
2     10180  71128.571429
3     13820  87338.396624
4     10420  76620.000000
...
```

Note that the same 'MSA Code" can appear multiple times in smaller_df, but exactly once in wage_keys.

```
   MSA Code  Line   RPP Wages
0     10180   1.0  91.2   71128.571429
1     10180   2.0  97.4   71128.571429
2     10180   3.0  78.7   71128.571429
3     10180   4.0  93.5   71128.571429
4     10420   1.0  90.4   76620.000000
...
```

I have the following code to do the mapping, by making a dictionary of wages:

```
flat_df = smaller_df.pivot(index='MSA Code', columns='Line')['RPP']
```

The problem is I lose a column!  My index column becomes row labels.

```
Line        1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0
MSA Code
10180      91.2   97.4   78.7   93.5
10420      90.4   95.8   77.4   91.8
10500      82.7   97.2   54.0   93.5
10540      94.6  100.1   87.4   93.4
10580     100.6   98.1  103.4  101.8
```

I've tried a number of different things and none of them yields what I want.
How can I get this pivot to keep MSA Code as the first column instead of converting it to row labels?

Comment: You just need `flat_df = smaller_df.pivot(index='MSA Code', columns='Line')['RPP'].reset_index()`

Comment: Wow.  That did it.  I can't believe how much time I spent on this. tx,